# Function is called 8 times when updating a geometry column

Tags: oracle

I was troubleshooting a slow query and I found out that a function is called 8 times per record when updating a geometry column. Here is what I have to reproduce this.

Database is ORACLE 11.2.0.4 on windows 64 bit.

```
create table test (id number(12,2),geometry mdsys.sdo_geometry)
/

create or replace package test_pck is
  g_counter pls_integer;
  function test(p_geometry mdsys.sdo_geometry) return mdsys.sdo_geometry;
end;
/ 

create or replace package body test_pck is
  function test(p_geometry mdsys.sdo_geometry) return mdsys.sdo_geometry
   is
   begin
     g_counter := g_counter + 1;
     return null;
   end;
end;
/ 

insert into test (id,geometry) values (1,mdsys.sdo_geometry(2001,90112,null,sdo_elem_info_array(1,2,1),mdsys.sdo_ordinate_array(0,0,1,1)));
```

So now we have table with one record and a function that adds 1 to a counter every time it is called. Lets update.

```
begin
   test_pck.g_counter := 0;

   update test
      set geometry = test_pck.test(geometry);

   dbms_output.put_line('Rows  :'||sql%rowcount);
   dbms_output.put_line('Calls :'||test_pck.g_counter);

end;
/
```

Resulting in:

```
Rows  :1
Calls :8
```

I found this result when I used plshprof on the real function and some real data, comparing a direct update statement and a cursor for loop. The cursor for loop was a lot faster. About 8 times as fast.

Update:

```
Subtree     Ind%    Function    Ind%    Descendants     Ind%    Calls   Ind%    Function Name
1361809599  98.6%   133354972   9.7%    1228454627  88.9%   300368  2.5%    NGM1.NGM_GML_PCK.GML_TO_SDO (Line 609)
```

Cursor for loop:

```
Subtree     Ind%    Function    Ind%    Descendants     Ind%    Calls   Ind%    Function Name
174298751   96.3%   19654282    10.9%   154644469   85.4%   37546   2.4%    NGM1.NGM_GML_PCK.GML_TO_SDO (Line 609)
```

Is this a known phenomenon? Looks very much like a bug to me.

**** Edit ****

Found an answer on Oracle Support.

You have to declare the function returning a geometry type to be deterministic to fix this problem.

```
create or replace package test_pck is
  g_counter pls_integer;
  function test(p_geometry mdsys.sdo_geometry) return mdsys.sdo_geometry deterministic;
end;
/ 

create or replace package body test_pck is
  function test(p_geometry mdsys.sdo_geometry) return mdsys.sdo_geometry deterministic
   is
   begin
     g_counter := g_counter + 1;
     return null;
   end;
end;
/
```

This fixes the problem for my test situation but not for my "real life" function. Possibly because that functions takes a CLOB as a parameter.